# Problem Building dschaefer / android-box2d

Tags: c++, android, eclipse, android-ndk, box2d

I'm trying to build [dschaefer android-box2d](http://github.com/dschaefer/android-box2d), and did follow the recipe.
I do get this error when trying to build the TestBox2d with eclipse:

---

make all
/cygdrive/c/android/android-ndk-r3/build/prebuilt/windows/arm-eabi-4.2.1/bin/arm-eabi-ld \
-nostdlib -shared -Bsymbolic --no-undefined \
-o obj/libtest.so obj/test.o -L../box2d/lib/android -lbox2d \
-L/cygdrive/c/android/android-ndk-r3/build/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/lib \
-llog -lc -lstdc++ -lm \
/cygdrive/c/android/android-ndk-r3/build/prebuilt/windows/arm-eabi-4.2.1/lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.2.1/interwork/libgcc.a \

/cygdrive/c/android/android-ndk-r3/build/prebuilt/windows/arm-eabi-4.2.1/bin/arm-eabi-ld: cannot find -lbox2d
make: *** [obj/libtest.so] Error 1

---

The only thing I did change was in the TestBox2d\Makefile where i did change the path to the NDK.

There are some other that have the same problem [HERE](http://markmail.org/message/akikscccxkqvs56w#query:Doug%20Schaefer%20box2d+page:1+mid:akikscccxkqvs56w+state:results) but I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the linker cannot find the library box2d.

What I think is the problem is that you have a relative path pointing to the location of the box2d library (`-L../box2d/lib/android`). If your build directory changes, your build will break. What you might want to do is substitute an absolute path for the box2d library (such as `-L/cygdrive/c/box2d/lib/android`). All of your other link paths to the NDK are absolute.

A better way would be to put the path to your box2d library in an environment variable and use this environment variable in your makefile.

Comment: Thanks that did work, it lead me to a whole new bunch of errors, but it was progress ;)